# Adding NTP daemon on petalinux

Tags: ntp, petalinux, ntpd

> I have added the ntp daemon on petalinux, but i am not getting ntpq command.
> Can someone guide me, how can I add/use the ntpq file on petalinux.

Answer (score 0):

ntpq exists as a separate package and requires that you explicitly call it out in your build.

open project-spec/meta-user/recipes-core/images/petalinux-image.bbappend
(filename may vary based on version of Petalinux you are using)

add this line
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " ntpq"

petalinux-config -c rootfs
user packages --> [*] ntpq

petalinux-build

For how to use ntpq refer to the man pages or ntpq --help.

Answer (score 0):

I got here from having a similar issue however the answer provided was insufficient for getting the `rootfs` configuration.  The full answer seems to be:

1. Locate `project-spec/meta-user/conf/user-rootfsconfig` and add the following lines:

   `CONFIG_ntp`

   `CONFIG_ntpq`
2. Locate `project-spec/meta-user/recipes-core/images/petalinux-image-full.bbappend` and add the following line:

   `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "ntp ntpq"`
3. Run `petalinux-config -c rootfs`, navigate to the `user packages` section.  You will now see `ntp` and `ntpq` as separate line items.  Enable them both.
4. Run `petalinux-build` and you'll see NTP downloaded and compiled.